# DataGridView AddRange, Cast IEnumerable<object[]> to DataGridViewRow[] (If possible, using LINQ)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, rows

If we want to add a row to a `DataGridView`, apart from adding a `DataGridViewRow` object, we could do it by passing an array of object (`object[]`)

```
dgv.Rows.Add(objArray); //objArray is of type object[]
```

However, if we want to add a range of rows to a `DataGridView`, we cannot pass `IEnumerable<object[]>`, but can only pass `DataGridViewRow[]`

```
dgv.Rows.AddRange(ienumObjArray); //not allowed, ienumObjArray is of type IEnumerable<object[]>
dgv.Rows.AddRange(dgvRows); //allowed, dgvRows is DataGridViewRow[]
```

My question: is there any way to cast `IEnumerable<object[]>` to `DataGridViewRow[]` (if possible with LINQ) such that we can do something like this

```
dgv.Rows.AddRange(ienumObjArray.DoSomethingWithLinq(x => doSomething));
```

and do not need to add the `object[]` one by one?

```
foreach(object[] objArray in ienumObjArray)
    dgv.Rows.Add(objArray); //adding one by one, is it possible to get rid this of?
```

Edit:

This is done on `WinForms`

Edit 2:

applying @abatishchev's suggestion (without `AddRange`), I encountered strange result. If I put:

```
ienumObjArray.Select(objArr => dgv.Rows.Add(objArr));
```

or

```
var result = ienumObjArray.Select(objArr => dgv.Rows.Add(objArr));
```

Then, the `dgv` does not have rows added.

But if I do any of these,

```
ienumObjArray.Select(objArr => dgv.Rows.Add(objArr)).ToArray();
ienumObjArray.Select(objArr => dgv.Rows.Add(objArr)).ToList();
ienumObjArray.Select(objArr => dgv.Rows.Add(objArr)).Count();

or 

var result = ienumObjArray.Select(objArr => dgv.Rows.Add(objArr))
foreach(int i in result){
    //do something
}
```

Then it works fine! Why is this so?

Comment: `ienumObjArray.Select(objArr => dgv.Rows.Add(objArr)).ToArray()`?

Comment: @abatishchev I tried that but it doesn't seem that we can add `dgv.Rows` that way... too bad :( `.ToArray()` returns `int[]`

Comment: Rows.Add() returns the number of a row added. So the array returned should contain indices

Comment: @abatishchev thanks! Your method actually works, except for some unexpected behavior to me. But thanks still! =)

Comment: You're very welcome! However I personally would stick with a foreach loop. I've used to prefer cryptic one-liners but if it's a serious application, I'd recommend to go with readability and maintainability over small size and fancy look.

Comment: @abatishchev thanks, in that case, I will just follow your recommendation.

Comment: Good choice! Using a side effect of a `Select` call wasn't a good idea. And of course you were getting "strange results" because of the LINQ deferred execution, e.g. **no** execution in the first 2 cases.

Comment: @IvanStoev I see... "deferred execution" it sounds similar to `Lazy` to me.

Comment: You can also add an `AddRange` extension method to `DataGridViewRowCollection` that accept `IEnumerable<object[]>`  as parameter.

Comment: @RezaAghaei that approach is really new for me. How do we do that? Can built-in method be extended and maintaining the same class name and other methods?

Comment: Yes you can add it, I posted an answer based on the comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an option you can add an `AddRange` extension method to `DataGridViewRowCollection` that accept `IEnumerable<object[]>` as parameter:

```
public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange(this DataGridViewRowCollection collection, IEnumerable<object[]> rows)
    {
        foreach (object[] item in rows)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information about extension methods:

- [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: I see, you are actually creating a new `class` derived from `DataGridView` --> `public static class DataGridViewExtensions : DataGridView` is this what you mean? I mean, is the name of the class actually maintained as `DataGridView`?

Comment: No, it's extension method. It actually extends`DataGridViewRowCollection`  class and add `AddRange(IEnumerable<object[]> rows)` to it.

Comment: Wow! but where do you place that `class`?

Comment: Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type. For client code written in C# and Visual Basic, there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

Comment: Put the class somewhere in your project. Like other normal classes. Just make sure to use its namespace in `using` parts in the form that you want to call it.

Comment: I see... This is cool, the first time I know it! =) thanks! Voted up and accepted.

Comment: You are welcome. You have used them before, for example `.ToList` method on `IEnumerable` or some other linq extension methods. But knowing that you also can create some extension method for other types opens new doors for you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback +1 to your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Here we can create a list of `DataGridViewRow` using linq with the `IEnumerable<object[]>`, so with this we can use the `AddRange` of `DataGridViewRowCollection`, so before it call the method. try to select a new `DataGridViewRow` see it:

```
dgv.Rows.AddRange(ienumObjArray.Select(cols => PrepareDataGridViewRow(dgv,cols)).ToArray());
```

*.*

```
private static DataGridViewRow PrepareDataGridViewRow(DataGridView dgv, object[] cols)
{
    var result = new DataGridViewRow();
    result.CreateCells(dgv,cols);
    return result;
};
```